# How to create a Custom Adapter for List Items that have buttons etc. *SIMPLE WAY*

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, simplecursoradapter, custom-adapter

I came across a number of these which answered the question but didn't exactly structure the classes in a matter I found expandable, a lot of the time it would override functions especially as I was using an `SimpleCursorAdapter` rather than a `BaseAdapter` which handles the population of `SQLite` data into the list item automatically on `getView`.

The code provided in my answer is provided as a way of showing you how to develop a `ListAdapter` which will add buttons that can handle click events, WITHOUT enabling click events on the list items or without fully overriding original draw events of the class your extending.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly your XML for the row, only the ID of the4 button needs to be updated in code if your going to make any changes to it, the rest is not required by the custom part:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/tag_row_layout"
     android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="wrap_content">

     <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/name"
          />
     <Button
          android:id="@+id/delete_button"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
          android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
          android:text="Do Stuff"
          />
</LinearLayout>
```

This is a very simple list view and using LinearLayout it'll just display the button next to the text, it's nothing amazing.

The next part then is to have the code for the Adapter like this...

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

    public CustomListAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, layout, c, from, to);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        convertView = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

        Button btn = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.delete_button);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new DeleteButton());

        return convertView;
    }

    protected final static class DeleteButton implements OnClickListener {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.e("TestButton", "It's been fired!!!");
        }
    }
}
```

You can then extend this to multiple buttons but creating more in the list item's `XML` and then by creating another `static class` in the `CustomListAdapter`. This is great for extending the `SimpleCursorAdapter` because it will still inject the right data into the correct text views.

Comment: why to post the question if you know the answer

Comment: Because a lot of people have asked the question and I found the answer to be complex and doesn't apply to extending more complex classes

Comment: Hey it work's fine . But i want to use

    ```textview tv=(TextView)findviewById(R.id.title);
    tv.settext(Html.fromHtml(myString));```

How ican i do this using Simplecursor adapteter..?